# rxjs - return subject with chained operators as subject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a BehaviourSubject like

```
taskStore$: BehaviorSubject<Task[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Task[]>([]);
```

for a store purpose in an ionic3 angular project.

I want to chain a "default" operator before returning it for subscription like

```
public subStore(logout$?: Subject<any>): BehaviorSubject<Task[]> {
        return this.taskStore$.takeUntil(logout$)
    }
```

but as far as I understand, operators turn Subjects into an Observable, which I don't want. The example above is that the subStore method always return a subject which "listens" to a logout broadcast for subscription management.

Comment: Please try to rephrase the problem. What is the expected behavior, and what is the observed behavior?

Comment: For what it's worth, subjects should never be exposed like that

Comment: @AluanHaddad could you evaluate or give me a reference why not?

Comment: @HanChe anyone who receives a reference to the subject can inject arbitrary events into the stream (or error it) for all existing subscribers.

Comment: but that's the idea of using it as a store, in face the whole ngrx is build on behavioursubjects, albeit i get you point that the values injectedt needs to be controlled

Comment: @HanChe sometimes that might be what you want but it still seems like a behavior that should be wrapped in some way. All of the advice I've seen says that a subject should be exposed as an `Observable` by calling `.asObservable()` which is exactly the opposite of what you seem to be after.

Comment: the reason is i'm trying to build modular components in angular while passing a subject as an input to it so it can govern certain actions on it's own, hence i need it to stay a subject, otherwise i'd totally agree